# logs not printing the full stack trace of exception in log file

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am trying to print the whole stack trace of exception in my log file without adding log.error statement in code as i have to make this generic implementation throughout the application. Can anyone help in this Here are log4j2 configuration xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration status="WARN">
  <appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>             
  </appenders>

         <logger name="org.springframework" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </logger>
  <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>

    </root>    

</configuration>
```

Comment: How are you expecting to log anything without a logger.error call? If you plan to use some other api method what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Without ever using a log.error statement it is not possible to pipe the output to a log-file via log4j2 xml configuration. However, there is one way to optimise this by handling you exceptions centrally at one place instead of doing this repeatedly in the code.

Write a separate class which will handle all exceptions ultimately, you can use 
`@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)`, this will handle all exceptions, in this you can intercept the exception and log out the full stack-trace using a `log.error(e)`. Annotating this class with `@ControllerAdvice(<all_pckages_you_want_cover>)` will ensure whenever an unhandled exception is raised it is finally intercepted at this point and logged.

Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/global-exception-handling-with-controlleradvice

PS: If you are asking about handled exceptions they are anyways going to be custom handled, so you add a single line for logging them in your catch block.